# Alterar nome do field no Jasper

Tags: jasper-reports

Estou montando um relatório e como trabalho com mais de uma tabela, existem nomes de campos iguais. O JasperStudio começou a adicionar os *fields* dando nomes como: COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, etc.

Minha pergunta é: Tem como alterar estes nomes sem ser colocando na *description*?
Quanto eu altero e tento executar o relatório, me retorna o erro:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Unknown column name id_projeto in result set.

Comment: Os campos que você se refere seria o nome das colunas em suas tabelas? Dê mais detalhes, se possível, post sua query.

Comment: Isso mesmo, são 2 campos. a query está assim: select u.firstname, u.lastname, wp.id, wp.subject, t.id, t.name, p.id, p.name, sum(hours) as horas, te.spent_on 
from time_entries te
inner join work_packages wp on wp.id = te.work_package_id
inner join users u on u.id = te.user_id
inner join types t on t.id = wp.type_id
inner join projects p on p.id = wp.project_id
where u.id = $P{usuario} 
and te.spent_on between $P{inicioApontamento} and $P{fimApontamento}
and t.id = 
and p.id = 
group by wp.id
order by te.spent_on

Comment: Você testo sua query? Cara, essa linguagem de banco de dados eu desconheço, mais você consegue armazenar este resultado em uma lista? Em que linguagem é sua aplicação?